# GetVMImageUrl doesn't work when Overriding

Tags: mdriven

I want to override in a ViewModel the way is showed a picture.

According to the DevelopmentView:
Picture for foto2

```
<div ng-show="ViewModelRoot.VM_Status.vmEditAlumno_foto2_Visible">
  <table>
    <thead>

    </thead><tbody>
      <tr>
        <img ng-src="{{StreamingViewModelClient.GetVMImageUrl(ViewModelRoot.Curr_vmEditAlumno(), "foto2")}}" img-responsive class="vmImage" />
      </tr><tr>
        <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onFileSelect('vmEditAlumno.foto2', angular.element(this).scope().ViewModelRoot.Curr_vmEditAlumno().VMClassId)" id="vmEditAlumno.foto2" ng-show="ViewModelRoot.VM_Status.vmEditAlumno_foto2_Enabled" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I set "Content Override" in the column and create a AngularUIOverride tag with value "Foto2Alumno.cshtml".

Not it gets the new file "Foto2Alumno.cshtml", as if I change something in that file it is showed, but the picture from the command GetVMImageUrl
isn't show

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with double quotes ("). I changed them to single quote (') and now the image is shown.

Wrong:
  GetVMImageUrl(ViewModelRoot.Curr_vmEditAlumno(), ***"foto2"***)

Right:
  GetVMImageUrl(ViewModelRoot.Curr_vmEditAlumno(), ***'foto2'***)